# Using USABoundaries

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the USABoundaries package to draw maps and am having trouble downloading UsaBoundariesData. When I enter something like this

```
library(USAboundaries)

OH_cong <- us_congressional(states = "OH", resolution = "high")
```

I get this error message:

```
The USAboundariesData package needs to be installed.
Install the USAboundariesData package? 

1: Yes
2: No

Selection: Yes
Installing the USAboundariesData package.
Installing package into ‘/home/rstudio-user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Failed to install the USAboundariesData package.
  Please try installing the package for yourself using the following command: 
     install.packages("USAboundariesData", repos = "http://packages.ropensci.org", type = "source")
> install.packages("USAboundariesData", repos = "http://packages.ropensci.org", type = "source")
Installing package into ‘/home/rstudio-user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in install.packages : error reading from connection
```

If anyone has any useful info that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Connor - this looks like a network error. I just tried `install.packages("USAboundariesData", repos = "http://packages.ropensci.org", type = "source")` and it worked without error.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/USAboundariesData")
```